# using "+" to combine two strings

Tags: java, string-concatenation

I have a class :

```
class Employee{...}
```

then :

```
Employee aEmployee = new Employee(...);
int i = 10;
String str = aEmployee + i;
```

it generates a ERROR when compiled, Why ?

**EDIT**:
I didn't override the `toString()` method in the `Employee` class, but if I try this:

```
Employee aEmployee = new Employee(...);
String h = "hello";
String str = aEmployee + h;
```

this time will be fine, both compiling and running.

So: why is it OK after changing the `int` variable `i` to a `String` variable `h`?

Comment: Override the *Object.toString()* method in `Employee` class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`aEmployee` is not a `String` it's an `Object`.

Without knowing how your `Employee` object is set up, it's difficut to provide you with a suitable solution, but ...

```
String str = aEmployee.toString() + i;
```

Will stop the compiler from complaining, but may not give you the result you're expecting.

You'd be better trying to perform this action with a known property of the`Employee`

```
String str = aEmployee.aMethodThatReturnsString() + i;
```

Comment: Essentially, the compiler has looked at the two values & decide that it can use the .toString() method of the aEmployee to concatenate the two values. This is a feature of the language. Before, it looked at te to values & couldn't duduce how he two values should be added together

Answer (score 4):

`Employee` is not a `String`, and cannot be concatenated using the `+` operator.

In fact, in Java, there is no such thing as operator overloading (besides a few that are baked into the language, `String` is a prime example of that).

Answer (score 1):

May be

```
String str = aEmployee.EName + i;
```

Where EName is a property of Employee Class and of type string

Answer (score 0):

`Employee aEmployee = new Employee(...);`

`aEmployee` is an **Object Reference Variable** of **Type Employee** pointing to **Employee object** on the heap.

`String str = aEmployee + i;`

In the above statement you are trying to concatenate a **String and an Object Reference Variable.**

Try doing this.....

`String str = aEmployee.toString() + i;`

If you have **not overridden** the `toString()` method in Employee class, then you will get something like this, `getClass().getName()@hashCode + i`

Comment: He is actually concatinating an Employee to an int

Comment: @ Ya thats what my answer explains...but i digged in to explain what actually aEmployee is....

Answer (score 0):

```
Employee aEmployee = new Employee(...);
```

aEmployee  is an object  reference not an String .so you can  not concatenate  it .

to combine you need to convert object to toString() then  can concatenate.

Answer (score 0):

Because `aEmployee` is a object of the `Employee` class so that object not belongs to the String class. if you need to concatenate with string you have to use `.toString()` method.

```
String str = aEmployee.toString() + i;
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason that the first example is failing to compile is because of the nature of the `+` operator.  In Java, `+` is an *overloaded* operator whose meaning depends on the static types of the left and right operand sub-expressions.

- If both operands are both primitive numeric types (or their wrapper types), the operator is a numeric addition.
- If either or both operands are Strings, the operator is a String concatenation.
- If neither of the above is true, the operator is not defined - a compilation error.

In your first example, `Employee` is neither a String or a number, and `i` is not a String either, so the `+` operator is not meaningful.

In the second example, you have changed the second operand to a String, so the operator is now recognized as a String concatenation.  In fact, the Java treats this as equivalent to:

```
    String str = aEmployee.toString() + h;
```

As a corollary, you could have made the first example compile by changing it to:

```
    String str = aEmployee.toString() + i;
```